# How do i rewriting a function code javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, array.prototype.map

A function that `returns a new array` that contains the product of `each pair of numbers` from the arguments that have *the same index*.

```js
var a = [3, 5, 7];
var b = [9, 10, 11];

a.map(function(x, index) { //here x = a[index] //how do i write this as function name(){}
  console.log(b[index] * x);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = [3, 5, 7];
var b = [9, 10, 11];

let c = [];

function name(a, b) {
    a.map(function(x, index) {
         let result = b[index] * x;
         c.push(result);
     }
}

name(a, b);
console.log(c) // this will show a new array with the results
```

Comment: how do i get the answer in this format [ , , ,] so far it returns it as separate values

Comment: I've edited the code to show a new array called c which will show the results in the array format [x, x, x]

Comment: Oh my god !!! You should get result from `.map` instead of `c.push(result)` !!!

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
var a = [3, 5, 7];
var b = [9, 10, 11];

function myFunction(x,index)
  {
  return (b[index] * x);
  }

var c = a.map(myFunction);

console.log( c )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the new value from the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback.

```js
var a = [3, 5, 7];
var b = [9, 10, 11];

const res = a.map((x,index)=>b[index] * x);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @niconi You should read this answer, it should work !!!

Comment: @niconi This should be the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The specs of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) say that:

> The map() method `creates a new array` populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var a = [3, 5, 7];
var b = [9, 10, 11];

function name(value_of_array_a, index_of_array_b) {
  return b[index_of_array_b] * value_of_array_a;
} 

var result = a.map(name);
console.log(result);
```